# Correct Format of "Server Name" for connecting to LocalDB SQL Server Named Instance

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed LocalDB option with SQL Server Express and I also have created it with a named instance of `LOCALDBSERVER`.

But in SQL Server Management Studio in the Server Name section I enter:

```
(localdb)\LOCALDBSERVER
```

and it cannot connect to it. But if I type `.\LOCALDBSERVER`  then it connects.

What am I doing wrong and what is the difference?

I have attached the screenshots I took from this `LOCALDBSERVER` while I was installing it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation screenshot looks like you installed another instance of SQL Server Express Edition, named LOCALDBSERVER. This is a named instance of SQL Express, not a localdb instance.

One way to create a localdb instance named LOCALDBSERVER is with the [sqllocaldb utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility) (assuming you have installed the localdb feature):

```
sqllocaldb create LOCALDBSERVER
```

You can then connect from SSMS with the '(localdb)\LOCALDBSERVER' specification.

Comment: OH WOW .. so to make sure I understood it:  " .\LOCALDBSERVER " connects to SQL Express version and  (localdb)\LOCALDBSERVER  connect to LocalDB ?  And two Different things?  Oh . I had no idea.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, different things. " .\LOCALDBSERVER" is another named instance, just like " .\SQLEXPRESS" is a separate named instance. You can similarly create multiple localdb instances with whatever names you like.